# Android supporting multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have a bit confusion about supporting different screen sizes. 

 
In android manual it's written that layout-large .. layout-xlarge ..etc are deprecated in android 3.2+, and we should use instead layout-swXXXdp ..

if I want to write an app that supports android API level +8, do i have to make two folders, one folder layout-large for APIs lower that 11, and another folder layout-600dp for APIs level 11 and above ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the pre-11 layouts in res/layout and put the 11+ versions of the layouts in res/layout-v11. Following the guidelines of the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) document

> The smallest-width qualifier is available only on Android 3.2 and above. Therefore, you should also still use the abstract size bins (small, normal, large and xlarge) to be compatible with earlier versions. For example, if you want to design your UI so that it shows a single-pane UI on phones but a multi-pane UI on 7" tablets, TVs and other large devices, you'd have to supply these files:
>
> res/layout/main.xml: single-pane layout
> res/layout-large: multi-pane layout
> res/layout-sw600dp: multi-pane layout

I don't think layout-large is deprecated. `layout-sw600dp` would work for API level greater than 11. On top of that, there are only a few devices which falls under sw600dp and are lower than api level 8.

Comment: according to this document, http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html .. it says that we better to use "aliased" layout to avoid duplication of layouts

Comment: Refer to this line `Therefore, you should also still use the abstract size bins (small, normal, large and xlarge) to be compatible with earlier versions.`